# repeat a vector to fill a column in r

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I have a data frame with around ~400,000 rows.  I need to create a new column in that `df` that is named `nearest_match_ID` and that column needs to be the numbers 1 through 253 repeating over and over all the way down.

So rows 1-253 will basically just have a value equal to their row number, but then row 254 starts back at 1, counting up to 253 at row 506, and then row 507 will be 1 again and so on.

I can print the df if that is helpful, but this seems simple enough that it might not be necessary.

Comment: See `help("rep")`. You're going to want to use the `length.out` argument; something like `rep(1:253, length.out = nrow(df))`

Comment: Can you use the recycling rule? `df$nearest_match_ID <- 1:253`

Answer (score 2):

```
df$nearest_match_ID <- seq_len(nrow(df)) %% 253L + 1L
```